# how can i change layout using onListItemClick() in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I try to to change the **layout** by clicking my `ListView`.

**This is my Java class.**

I have an `ArrayList` of *bus_routes*

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bus_routes)));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="listview.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />                             <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Array List**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="bus_routes">
            <item>100 Pettah to Panadura</item>
            <item>101 Pettah to Moratuwa</item>
            <item>102 Kotahena to Moratuwa</item>
            <item>103 Fort to Borella</item>
            <item>104 Bambalapitya to Wattala</item>
            <item>107 Fort to Elakanda</item>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: When i click Listview layout will not change.... when i click My phone showing my app has stop..

Comment: When click on Row `onListItemClick` method is executing ? use log to check

Comment: No, it wont execute when i click row logcat showing lot of errors (Red clolor)

Comment: So would you mind posting those "lot of errors"? They might be the reason why the program isn't doing what you expect. Just sayin...

Comment: Post the error from LogCat please.  If that's the entirety of your code then there is no reason for it to be Force Closing.

Comment: 02-17 22:23:32.994: E/EmbeddedLogger(796): App crashed! Process: listview.com
02-17 22:23:32.994: E/EmbeddedLogger(796): App crashed! Package: listview.com v1 (1.0)
02-17 22:23:32.994: E/AndroidRuntime(14524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 22:23:32.994: E/AndroidRuntime(14524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{listview.com/listview.com.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` - this applies for the layout of the Second activity.

Comment: public class Second extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.second);
 }
 
} My Second class

Comment: i have doubt insight onListItemClick() method have to add some code to get position to clicked object ??????

Answer (score 1):

When your activity inherits from ListActivity, you're obligated to add a `ListView` whose id is `android.R.id.list` into the activity's layout.

From the logs, if your Second Activity's content is not a list, then you must inherit from the `Activity` instead of `ListActivity`. If your Second Activity's content is a list, then in your `second.xml` layout, you must add a ListView item with whose id is `android.R.id.list`.

Comment: This is my second class class ublic class Second extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.second);
 }
}

Comment: I think their is error insight onListItemClick() method before define a Intent object we have to find which position which row clicked???

Comment: Modify your Second Activity to extend from Activity instead of ListActivity in order to avoid .The position of the selected item index comes in the onListItemClick attributes as **int position**. If you want to get the selected item, the ArrayAdapter<String> instance comes with a method getItem(int position) that will return the required item at the provided position